# Accepted incorrect but useful answer

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, upvotes

I recently posted an answer for a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288395/save-an-enum-in-randomaccessfile/30289256?noredirect=1#comment48707218_30289256) which was not well prepered, without MCVE or description of input format. I decided to answer it, though I couldn't verify if my answer was working in that particular case becouse of incomplete example. My answer was accepted, although as OP commented it didn't solve his problem, but gave him idea how to do it. He also posted his own solution. I asked him to undo acceptance of my answer and upvote it instead, but I am not sure what it proper behaviour.

1. Is it appropriate to accept a incorrect but useful answer?
2. Did I make mistake that I posted an answer without certainty that I am right?
3. Is upvoting of a incorrect but useful answer a good practice?
4. Did I make mistake, answering such question at all?

If it was possible to verify answer, but I would give incorrect one, I wouldn't have any doubts, but what in a case of vague questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Well, the question author is free to accept whatever post they want; we certainly can't *stop* them from doing this, whether we agree with their decision or not.
2. You don't necessarily need to be *certain* (I mean, nobody can be *certain* of anything.), but you should be pretty confident.  Given your own description of the question it seems to have been quite unclear, and you were taking a guess with a fairly low level of certainty.  *That* should be avoided; instead ask clarifying questions to help the author improve the question such that you can post an answer with confidence.  Answering unclear questions, as you have now seen, causes a lot of problems.

   This is why unclear questions are closed as "unclear" until the author can improve them; it helps to prevent problems like these before they happen.
3. If the answer *really* is useful, then upvoting it is appropriate, but if the answer is incorrect one should be questioning whether or not it really is a useful post.

   Generally, if the portion(s) of the answer that aren't correct are more tangential to the question, and the core of the answer is the proper solution, or if the things making it incorrect are minor errors that can be easily found and corrected by other answerers, then the answer can still be useful.  Having said that, if its your own answer and you know what's wrong, ideally you'd fix it rather than leaving the answer incorrect.

   Again, like with accepting, at the end of the day people can vote however we want.  If an answer is just completely off base and not even close to being the right answer, we still can't *stop* people from upvoting it, despite whatever problems it might have, but such a person really is being harmful if they don't actually think the answer they're upvoting is a useful answer to the question.
4. See #2.